# sdkmanager --list Exception in thread "main"

Tags: android, windows-10, command-line-tool

In an attempt to list all available Android SDK packages, I used windows terminal and navigated to the %ANDROID_HOME%/tools/bin directory on Windows 10 Pro. I then tried running the Android  " sdkmanager --list"  command after following all instructions here:

https://developer.android.com/tools#tools-sdk

I expected the following:

Installed packages:
Path | Version | Description | Location
-------|---------|-------------|----------
| 31.0.3  | build-tools;31.0.3 | build-tools\31.0.3

Available Packages:
Path                             | Version | Description
-------|---------|-------------

Instead, received this exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at
java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
... 5 more

C:\Users\mainUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools>